# Direct my function's output to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
import re

def matches(line, opendelim='(', closedelim=')'):
    stack = []
    for m in re.finditer(r'[{}{}]'.format(opendelim, closedelim), line):
        pos = m.start()
        if line[pos-1] == '\\':
            continue
        c = line[pos]
        if c == opendelim:
            stack.append(pos+1)
        elif c == closedelim:
            if len(stack) > 0:
                prevpos = stack.pop()
                yield (line[prevpos:pos], len(stack))
            else:
                print("encountered extraneous closing quote at pos {}: '{}'".format(pos, line[pos:] ))
            pass
    if len(stack) > 0:
        for pos in stack:
             print("expecting closing quote to match open quote starting at: '{}'"
              .format(line[pos-1:]))

line = "f(g_1(a, g_2(a, b, g_3(c)), g_2(g_3(a, b, g_4(a), e))))"
a = str(print(','.join([part for part, level in matches(line) if level == 1])))
print(extract_tokens(a))
```

Which it returns when I run the two functions separately. How can I get my output while running them in a single script file?

Comment: Your indentation is broken, your code is lengthy. Heard about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's impossible to tell which lines are inside the functions and which are at global level.

Comment: `print` doesn't `return` anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `print` will *always* `return None`, so this line:

```
a = str(print(','.join([part for part, level in matches(line) if level == 1])))
```

is equivalent to:

```
print(...)
a = str(None)
```

Therefore when you run:

```
print(extract_tokens(a))
```

you get `['None']` as an output. The problem is **not** with calling the functions, but the argument you're passing. Put `print(a)` on a separate line and you should be fine.